# How am I supposed to extract properties from a node in Apache Jackrabbit from xml?

Tags: java, jcr, jackrabbit

I have been playing around with the example number three in here http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/first-hops.html , however to me it remains unclear how to get access to the properties of a node.

In the first screenshot
[image: Have access to jcr prop]

I used the debugger from my IDE and I evaluated this expression

```
session.getNode("/importxml/xhtml:html/xhtml:body/mathml:math/mathml:apply/mathml:apply[2]/mathml:apply[2]/mathml:cn").getProperty("jcr:xmltext/jcr:xmlcharacters").getString().trim();
```

You can see how I can get access to "jcr:xmltest/jcr:xmlcharacters" and have 2 as a result.
However, when I try to get this information, get this property out of the node, I am unable to perform this operation as in this screenshot.
[image: Cannot get props]

This is the code fragment in the above screenshot:

```
var node = session.getNode("/importxml/xhtml:html/xhtml:body/mathml:math/mathml:apply/mathml:apply[2]/mathml:apply[2]/mathml:cn");
var properties = node.getProperties();
List<string> result = new ArrayList<>();
while(properties.hasNext()) {
    Property property = properties.nextProperty();
    result.add(property.getString().trim());
}
return result;
```

You can see how I get as a response only a value containing "nt:unstructured".

Unfortunately I couldn't find many code examples online, on Github, etc. many outdated, and also, there are not books as there are for Scrapy or other libraries/frameworks.

Thank you in advance.

Have a nice day!

Davide

Comment: I'm willing to help in case you rephrase this in a way that doesn't require staring at screenshots.

Comment: I added the code fragments to the post.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you are looking at the properties of:

```
/importxml/xhtml:html/xhtml:body/mathml:math/mathml:apply/mathml:apply[2]/mathml:apply[2]/mathml:cn/jcr:xmltext
```

In the second case:

```
/importxml/xhtml:html/xhtml:body/mathml:math/mathml:apply/mathml:apply[2]/mathml:apply[2]/mathml:cn
```

Note the different paths.